# Why doesn't this code return an array of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy

In running the following code:

```
f=lambda m,n: (m,n)
np.fromfunction(f,(6,6),dtype=int)
```

I get the following output:

```
(array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]), array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]))
```

Why don't I get an array/list of tuples?

My expectation came from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html

```
numpy.fromfunction(function, shape, **kwargs)
Construct an array by executing a function over each coordinate.

The resulting array therefore has a value fn(x, y, z) at coordinate (x, y, z).
```

My function f(n,m) returns (n,m).

```
f2=lambda m,n: m+10*n
np.fromfunction(f2,(6,6),dtype=int)
```

gives the following output

```
array([[ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
       [ 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51],
       [ 2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52],
       [ 3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53],
       [ 4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54],
       [ 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55]])
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to be an array of tuples?

Comment: Please quote the portion of the documentation that you read that makes you think your expectation is reasonable.

Comment: You are very unlikely to get individual explanations for all the downvotes. You are lucky that you got two explanations. Three point to take away from this, in my opinion, is that you should fix the things you know, like asking a complete question, rather than attempting to shift that onus onto the community. Remember, you have a problem, not us, and we are helping you fix it for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromfunction` docs can be confusing.  But if you look at the code you'll see that it simply generates `indices` and passes them **whole** to your function:

```
In [345]: f = lambda m,n: (m,n)                                                                
In [346]: np.fromfunction(f, (3,3), dtype=int)                                                 
Out[346]: 
(array([[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]]), array([[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]))
In [348]: m,n = np.indices((3,3))                                                              
In [349]: m,n                                                                                  
Out[349]: 
(array([[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]]), array([[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]))
```

There is a function that will feed tuples to your function:

```
In [351]: np.frompyfunc(f,2,1)(m,n)                                                            
Out[351]: 
array([[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
       [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)],
       [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]], dtype=object)
```

`np.vectorize` does something similar, but for this purpose `frompyfunc` is simpler and faster.

This list comprehension is just as fast:

```
In [352]: [(i,j) for i,j in zip(m.ravel(),n.ravel())]                                          
Out[352]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Your second function:

```
In [414]: m,n = np.indices((3,3))                                                              
In [415]: m*10*n                                                                               
Out[415]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10, 20],
       [ 0, 20, 40]])
```

The actual code:

```
def fromfunction(function, shape, **kwargs):
    dtype = kwargs.pop('dtype', float)
    args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
```

====

```
f2=lambda m,n: m+10*n
```

works in both `np.fromfunction` and `np.frompyfunc`.

```
In [417]: f2=lambda m,n: m+10*n                                                                
In [418]: np.fromfunction(f2, (3,3), dtype=int)                                                
Out[418]: 
array([[ 0, 10, 20],
       [ 1, 11, 21],
       [ 2, 12, 22]])
In [420]: np.frompyfunc(f2,2,1)(m,n)                                                           
Out[420]: 
array([[0, 10, 20],
       [1, 11, 21],
       [2, 12, 22]], dtype=object)
```

===

Here's function that will return 3d array equivalent of your nested tuples:

```
In [426]: f3 = lambda m,n: np.stack((m,n), axis=2)                                             
In [427]: np.fromfunction(f3,(3,3),dtype=int)                                                  
Out[427]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
In [428]: f3(m,n)                                                                              
Out[428]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I still have some doubts, though... I've edited (2nd one) my post with a new example. I don't get why in for some function, what it receives is indices, and it works, but for some other function, those same indices don't work. This behaviour doesn't seem to be very consistent...

Comment: Your 2nd example is what I expect,  the Out[349] `m+10*n`.  There's nothing profound about the function.  `np.arange(6)[:,None]+10*np.arange(6)` does the same thing.

Comment: This is a case where the code is clearer than the documentation.  The *"The resulting array therefore has a value fn(x, y, z) at coordinate (x, y, z)."* might be interpreted in the `frompyfunc` sense, but the code clearly shows otherwise.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. The last code is still too advanced for me. I'll study a bit more Python, and maybe I'll get it some day. =D  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The only thing that `fromfunction` streamlines is the generation of the `indicies`.  You still have to write a function that works with whole arrays.  I added a function that creates a 3d version of the nested tuples.